# Получение списка из списка кортежей (списка колонок из списка рядов)

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть список кортежей:

```
[('name', 'age', 'gender'), ('dima', '25', 'male')]
```

Как в итоге получить список такого вида:

```
[('name', 'dima'), ('age', '25'), ('gender', 'male')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [('name', 'age', 'gender'), ('dima', '25', 'male')]
zip(*data)
```

Comment: Словами это можно описать как [*транспонирование матрицы*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)